# ExtJS RowEditor How to render all the component validation on load

Tags: extjs, editor, rendering, gridpanel

Hi everyone i got the following issue, i have a GridPanel with a RowEditor Nevertheless it doesnt validate my fields when it renders 
[image]

But if i focus all my fields to edit and refresh the grid its just appear as i would like them in the first place

[image]

Can you suggest me something? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RowEditor uses **Ext.form** package components such as: "TextField" "DateField" "ComboBox" and so on... And validations are performed by them. Grid does't have such feature to validate. Validation feature may be achieved by **renderer** config option of column. For example, your Description column config might be looked like this:

```
{
    header    : 'Description',
    dataIndex : 'description',
    renderer  :function(description, metaData){
        if(!description){
            //if description is blank let background of it be red.
            medaData.style+="background-color:red;"; //or whatever css can be applied
        }
        return description;
    }
}
```